# Scraping a challenging seemingly HTML table using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

While looking for tough websites to read data from, I find a good case study in the following. I have solved it using a brute force and an inelegant solution. However, I am sure their is an elegant way to deconstruct the table from this page (BoxBg1 element).

I can get each element of the table using individual x-paths of the page: https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/3mindia/balance-sheetVI/MI42

For example, 'Reserves and Surplus' for March 2018 is 
'/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]'

The value can be easily extracted using code:

```py
    from selenium import webdriver


    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/3mindia/balance-sheetVI/MI42')
    trial_xpath ='/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[9]/td[3]'
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(trial_xpath).text)
```

Likewise, I have obtained all elements. But how do I neatly obtain the table using the bigger element xpath or css_selector, etc

xpath of the table is: `'//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "boxBg1", " " ))] | //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "hed", " " ))]'`

It's fine if the 'bold' text is not retrievable, they are derived from the rest of the table data itself.

I have tried looping over using `find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr')` as well, like described in the following code. Alas, it didn't work and generates an invalid error in the python console.

```py
    Whole_table_xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "boxBg1", " " ))] | //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "hed", " " ))]'

    Whole_table_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(Whole_table_xpath)
    for i in Whole_table_element.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tr'):
        print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(i).text)
        print(driver.find_element_by_xpath(i).get_attribute("value"))
```

Comment: This site doesn't seem particularly difficult to scrape, but are you sure the site allows scraping? In case you are sure, you can have a look at the bs4 (BeautifulSoup) package.

Comment: Using bs4 on 'table4' element.. I think it has the core tabular data?
It has a specific xpath: /html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]

Comment: _...obtain the table..._ Which data are you exactly looking for?

Comment: @DebanjanB - I'm looking for the main balance sheet data. It is under table4 element. But there are multiple table4 elements. The xpath to the correct table4 element is (same as in my previous table): /html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]

Comment: I understand _there are multiple table4 elements_. Are you asking to extract all the data from the whole table?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for an elegant solution and learn from it. So far, I can read it all using individual xpaths... but this is a very ugly repetitive code (works though)!

I figured I must be missing some HTML parsing skills!